# Django modal form requiring a value

Tags: html, django, forms, action

I'm facing an issue that I have a small modal form pop up when I click on a button and taking a product ID value from a text field and when the user click on submit it should be redirected to the product view.

the issue in the action section it's requiring a primary key even before the main page lunched and it's showing the below error

```
NoReverseMatch at /products all
Reverse for 'ProductDetail2' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried:   ['ProductDetail2/(?P<pk>[^/]+)$']
```

below is the modal form:

```html
<div class="modal-body">
  <form method="POST" action="{% url 'ProductDetail2' ProdID %} %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-group">
      <label style="float: right;" for="ProdID"> : رقم المنتج</label>
      <input
        style="float: right;"
        type="text"
        class="form-control"
        id="ProdID"
        aria-describedby="emailHelp"
      />
      <br /><br /><br />
      <small id="emailHelp" style="float: right;" class="form-text text-muted"
        >إبحث برقم المنتج ثم إضغط على الذهاب للمنتج</small
      >
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">الذهاب للمنتج</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

and this is the URL

`path('ProductDetail2/<pk>',views.ProductDetail2,name="ProductDetail2"),`

if I pass a fixed value like below

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'ProductDetail2' 90 %}  %}">
```

the main page will launched without no error and if I click on the submit button even with no input it will direct me to the ProductDetail2 view for product 90 with no error

I need to replace the **90** value with the value of the text input field

```
<input style="float: right;" type="text" class="form-control" id="ProdID" aria-describedby="emailHelp" >
```

Answer (score 0):

You should write like this in model form

`<form method="POST" action="{% url 'ProductDetail2' ProdID %}">`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of asking user to enter the product id , list all the available product ids and call the product view. assuming there are only few product ids.

Comment: i think this give a error<form method="POST" action="{% url 'ProductDetail2' ProdID %}ProdID %}">

Comment: he passes a couple of ProdID like ProdID%} ProdID%}

Comment: I have given a more detailed answer. hope it helps.

Comment: actually the idea is to use a barcode reader to get the product ID, letting the user to type the ID manually just the beginning, also incase there's a lot of products it will be much deficit to handle the list @Neeraj, thank you for your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

What I meant was..
`<a href="{% url 'ProductDetail2' prodid1 %}"> Product1</a> <a href="{% url 'ProductDetail2' prodid2 %}"> Product2</a> <a href="{% url 'ProductDetail2' prodid3 %}"> Product3</a>` 
form not required.

Comment: as I explain your method will work perfectly in case I list all the products in table, but since I'm trying to use a barcode reader which going to pass the ID I need to let the user type it manually incase the barcode reader didn't read it correctly

Comment: you can use Ajax. get the product id from user, send an Ajax Get request to server and retrieve the product details.